# Add controller path for routes in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am working on a rails migration project (From rails 2 to rails 4)

So I have a folder under my rails root directory called "template_actions" and this folder has subdirectories that can have a controller in it(I cant change it.. thats how they have designed the structure).

So to allow these paths to be considered, my routes.rb was like this.

```
allControllers= ActionController::Routing.possible_controllers + Actions.all_template_action_controllers #Returns controller names
ActionController::Routing.use_controllers!(allControllers)
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
```

I want this same thing in rails 4.

```
allControllers = Actions.all_template_action_controllers + Rails.application.routes.routes 
Rails.application.routes.draw do
```

I tried the above and it crashes saying '+' is not allowed.

Any idea how to get this working?

**OUTPUT Requested in Comments:**

Rails.application.routes.routes - Outputs a class.

But each on it and puts prints the below.

```
#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Route:0x007f88de078320 @name=nil, @app=#<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Constraints:0x007f88de078c08 @dispatcher=false, @app=#<Sprockets::Environment:0x3fc46c977f78 root="abcd", paths=["abcd/app/assets/images", "abcd/app/assets/javascripts", "abcd/app/assets/stylesheets", "abcd/vendor/assets/javascripts", "abcd/vendor/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/qwerty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.2.1/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/qwerty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.1.1/lib/assets/javascripts", "/Users/qwerty/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/turbolinks-source-5.0.0/lib/assets/javascripts"]>, @constraints=[]>, @path=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Path::Pattern:0x007f88de078b40 @spec=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Cat:0x007f88de078e38 @left=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Slash:0x007f88de079180 @left="/", @memo=nil>, @memo=nil, @right=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Nodes::Literal:0x007f88de078ed8 @left="assets", @memo=nil>>, @requirements={}, @separators="/.?", @anchored=false, @names=[], @optional_names=nil, @required_names=nil, @re=nil, @offsets=nil>, @constraints={:required_defaults=>[]}, @defaults={}, @required_defaults=nil, @required_parts=nil, @parts=nil, @decorated_ast=nil, @precedence=0, @path_formatter=#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Format:0x007f88de0781b8 @parts=["/", "assets"], @children=[], @parameters=[]>>
```

Comment: As somebody that has no idea what these do, what do `ActionController::Routing.possible_controllers` and `Rails.application.routes.routes` actually output? Can you add a puts/inspect statement in there or something?